# Using classes from wsimport -target 2.0 in Eclipse maven Project JavaSE-11

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm not sure why it isn't working, because it hat worked in the past before things changed, but now, when I make an wsimport in Linux bash and even though the Folder is in the build path, Eclipse doesn't show the Classes as expected.

The package can be seen, but the classes inside of it not, even though it looks right on the file system.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to not use the Folder as source (as it had no java Files) but as class Folder in classpath